# storing string in an integer array.

Tags: java

I am trying to store a string into an integer array with the following code:

```
public LargeInteger(String s) {      
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        intArray[i] =  Integer.parseInt( s.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

eclipse is giving me an error saying: the method parseInt(string) is not applicable for the arguments (char)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to parse the `char`, or convert it to a `String`.

If you're trying to get one digit at a time, and you know your input is a digit, then the easiest way to convert a single digit to an `int` is just

```
intArray[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10); // in base 10
```

If you want to keep using `Integer.parseInt`, then just do

```
intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
// or
intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i+1));
```

Comment: thanks, This makes sense but I am still getting an error probably because of something else I am doing wrong..

Answer (score 1):

That's because `Integer.parseInt()` expects a `String` as parameter, while you are passing a `char` (`s.charAt()` returns a `char`).

Since you are creating the array one digit at a time, a better way to get the decimal representation would be:

```
intArray[i] = s.charAt(i) - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

char is not a String so use a substring function `s.substring(i, i+1)` or better `intArray[i] =  s.charAt(i)`

Answer (score 0):

`s.charAt` returns a char.
+ `parseInt` take a `String`
= Eclipse gives you the compilation error

You may create a String from the char if really needed:

```
s.charAt(i)+""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] split = s.split("");
int[] nums = new int[split.length];
for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
  nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Storing_String_to_IntegerArray 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(" Q.37 Can you store string in array of integers. Try it.");

        String str="I am Akash";
        int arr[]=new int[str.length()];
        char chArr[]=str.toCharArray();
          char  ch;
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {

            arr[i]=chArr[i];
        }
        System.out.println("\nI have stored it in array by using ASCII value");
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {

            System.out.print(" "+arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\nI have stored it in array by using ASCII value to original content");
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
             ch=(char)arr[i];

            System.out.print(" "+ch);
        }
    }

}
```